# Azure function taking more time to complete and throw timeout error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I developed the Azure function which taking the records of 800 users from the db and update the user info by raising the update request which takes 11 minutes in local as the Async with await calls. When I deployed in the Azure it taking more time to run and being idle for long time finally showing the timeout error.

I set the timeout of function as 15 minutes and 30 minutes but am facing the same issue. Anyone help me out on this?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: 11 minutes to update a DB? it is too long

Comment: The function calling one API and send the Json string to update the profile.not a direct DB update.

Comment: 11 minutes is just too much unless you are dealing with GB of data

Comment: Does your Azure function invoke a stored procedure? Could you post your stored procedure / Azure function as this would help us to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Are you using a consumption based funciton? Because the time out limit on that is 10 minutes max.

Answer (score 0):

What I don't understand is why do you use Azure Functions at all in a case when there is a API which you are calling from the function. Why not call the API directly?

I would also suggest using an Azure Queue for such operation requests. Will be much more cost effective than running long operations.